# restfull htaccess rewrite condition not geting applied

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bit of a understanding problem with a rule. It should work but i think i am missing somthing. Help is Appriciated :)

Rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule   %{ENV:BASE}^(.+)/(\w+?)/(\w+?)$       %{ENV:BASE}handler.php?path=$1&class=$2&method=$3 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

It shold convert this url:

http://sccatdev.office.dig/deploy/ajax/Approval/Article/test

to 
http://sccatdev.office.dig/deploy/ajax/handler.php?path=Approval&class=Artile&method=test together with posts and gets.

But it semms im missing somthing. The .htaccess is located in the ajax folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues:

1. `%{ENV:BASE}` being an env variable cannot be used in rewrite pattern
2. `RewriteRule` pattern match URI relative to current directory, not the full path match.

If `.htaccess` is located inside `ajax` folder then you don't even need `%{ENV:BASE}` variable to rewrite. Just use following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ handler.php?path=$1&class=$2&method=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you wery much for  the pointers. 
But your rule dous not get triggerd. It is in the ajax folder.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Yes it is enabled. I am wokring on a workaround for now.